# Flash Catch game with Timer Countdown

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Please see the attachment
http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/fg

new to actionscript need project require help,

THis is a catch game m using as prototype which requires to have 1 min timer and on completion should show the score

Any help is appreciated in advance

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual about timers here - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000,8);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);

function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
    trace("Timer is Triggered");
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for quick response bt i read this cant figure to use in external as can you suggest